# IIS Site Getting Hacked?

Tags: mysql, sql, iis

I am running IIS 8.5 on a Windows 2012 R2 virtual server.

The server has MySQL Server 5.5.44 installed, and I connect to it using Classic ASP pages via a MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver.

Recently I have been getting issues in my error log with errors such as:

```
[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.44]Error on delete of 'C:\Windows\TEMP\#sql1718_1ca27_2d.MYI' (Errcode: 13)
```

And

```
[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.44]Can't find file: 'v_pdf_log' (errno: 2)
```

I have been able to normally go into the MySQL admin application (SQLYog) and repair the database, and the problem is fixed.

However, I think someone is trying to break the site as some strange URLs are getting called, such as:

```
mysite/mypage.asp?id=999999.9"+%2f**%2fuNiOn%2f**%2faLl+%2f**%2fsElEcT+0x393133353134353632312e39+and+"0"="0
```

These are URLs from Moscow. Presumably this is an SQL Injection attack is it?

Can they somehow delete actual MD Files from the MySQL folder? Presumably not, but they have done something.

And yes, I'm a stupid person who didn't parameterise my queries in my code...

Comment: If you're not sanitizing your parameters, you're probably already hacked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Parameterized queries and give the DB login the least privilege possible.

Also use stored procedures whenever possible

Comment: This except don't use stored procedures whenever possible

Comment: Use stored procedures where they are appropriate, yes; "whenever possible", no.